# Zebra Striping fails in Spring Roo

Tags: css, spring-roo

Why does the zebra striping in Spring Roo work in FireFox, Chrome, and Opera but fails in Internet Explorer 9?

Take any of the examples. I used pet clinic and pizza shop. Fill in any of the data to display a list. Notice that the lists in Internet Explorer 9 displays all grey.

I tracked this down to standard.css and the

table tr:nth-child(odd) 
table tr:nth-child(even)

fail to override the

table {
    background: ...
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

After much trial and error I discovered that the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

was being added by

default.jspx

I edited this to be

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;IE=9" />
```

and now the zebra striping works in Internet Explorer 9

Comment: Thanks. I just had a similar problem with roo and the meta set to IE8, which was forcing IE9 to IE8 document mode.

Comment: I also had the same problem.. now, I only remember I had to add the IE=8 part because something in IE9 needed compatibility with IE8 to work, and now I can't remember what it was... it's en endless circle eating itself that ie :D but everything works so far so.. +1 and thanks